# JSON String to Object

Tags: java, json

I do have a  **JSON String request** which uses JAXB to  convert to number instead of fields

```
"{\"1\":{\"3\":\"788888\",\"2\":\"12345\",\"0\":{\"0\":\"Login\",\"1\":\"xx\",\"2\":\"yy\",\"3\":\"\",\"4\":\"1\",\"5\":\"hhh\"}}}"
```

And the response which we get is also in the above format

Is there any way to  convert **JSON String Response** to Object where the object instance should be field values instead of numbers(keys)?

Note:-I had annotated(JAXB) fields in Request/Response class?

Comment: Are you aware that you're double-encoding your JSON? Correct JSON would start like `{"1":{"3":"788888","2":"12345"...`

Comment: @Tomalak yes...fields are being encoded as numbers instead of corresponding instances.the correct string should be

"{\"BnakCode\":{\"BankName\":\"788888\",\"ZipCode\":\"12345\",\"0\":.....}" etc

Comment: But that would *still* be double encoded. This looks right to me `{"BnakCode":{"BankName":"788888","ZipCode":"12345","0":.....}`. Your string is what you get when you put that through JSON encode *again*, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Tomalak What I need is to take the response which should be in the same format like {"1":{"3":"788888","2":"12345"..} which should be converted to response object instance. ie Mapping  the reponse calss fields to corresponding numbers